# Selecting a range from a specific cell and then special paste that range using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

i have an excel file in which i have data month wise, so i want to select Column F, G and H from the active cell till the last data of that column and then special paste it.
I am using this Code for selecting that range but not able to do that. it is selecting the data from the F1.

```
Sub selecting_range()
Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
currentcell = ActiveCell
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F" & currentcell).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("F1:H" & LastRow)
rng.Select
End Sub
```

[image: here is the snippet of my excel in which i want to select range from 'F11527']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the fact that the "F" and "H" are hardcoded, then you can build up something like this:

```
Sub SelectingRange()

    Dim rng             As Range
    Dim lastRow         As Long

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "F"), Cells(lastRow, "H"))

    rng.Select

End Sub
```

Or you can write it in 1-line, just to confuse someone:

```
Sub SelectingRange()
 Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "F"), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row, "H")).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Vityata. it is working as i want